# How to return null if not exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm using oracle plsql and I have a question. I have table of Tests and Table of Schools.

How can I make a query that will put null or some other by my demands?

I mean, to put null or some numeric number in the execution.

Comment: Have you tried something yet?  A simple `LEFT JOIN` would probably do what you want.

Comment: I have no example. Just the idea. Have you any examply for this left join or something?

Comment: A "left join" is really a "left OUTER join", the important distinction here being between an INNER JOIN and an OUTER JOIN. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this:

**Schools-table**

```
create table schools (name varchar(20));

insert into schools values ('Harvard');
insert into schools values ('Oxford');
insert into schools values ('Cambridge');
```

**Tests-table**

```
create table tests (name varchar(20), school varchar(20));

insert into tests values ('Math', 'Harvard');
insert into tests values ('Math', 'Oxford');
```

**Left join**

```
select
    s.name,
    t.name
from
    schools s
left join
    tests t on t.school = s.name;
```

**Output**

```
|      name |   name |
|-----------|--------|
|   Harvard |   Math |
|    Oxford |   Math |
| Cambridge | (null) |
```